# Memory leak using google charts with ajax

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-visualization

I'm fairly new to javascript and I'm having trouble finding a memory leak in some code which updates a google chart each second with ajax data.

My code (simplified to a small test case):

```
function TimeLine(id, max) {
    this.chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(id));
    this.vals = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    this.vals.addColumn('number', 'Index');

    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this.vals.addColumn('number', arguments[i]);
    }

    this.numCols = arguments.length - 2;
    this.max = max;
    this.index = 0;

    this.resourceOptions = {
        'title': 'Memory allocation',
            'width': 360,
        'height': 300
    };
}

TimeLine.prototype.Add = function () {

    if (this.vals.getNumberOfRows() > this.max) {
        this.vals.removeRow(0);
    }

    var row = [this.index];

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        row.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    this.vals.addRow(row);

    this.chart.draw(this.vals, this.options);

    this.index++;
};

function onLoad() {
    window.Timeline = new TimeLine('gauges', 15, 'Alloc');
    drawCharts();
}

function drawCharts() {
    window.Timeline.Add(window.Timeline.index%3);

    setTimeout(drawCharts, 1000);
}

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

I'm using chrome Version 29.0.1547.62 on 64 bit Ubuntu.

I wrapped the chart in an object to (hopefully) make it easier for me to reason about scope and garbage collection since I'm not quite used to the JS scoping rules. I've seen many questions on SO which are similar, but as far as I can tell my code shouldn't produce a leak. Using the memory timeline I can see the memory climb each time drawCharts is called and most of that memory seems to be gc'd, but after around an hour I'm up to 300 MB for that tab, and it just keeps climbing until the tab crashes. The goal is to be able to keep this tab up for extended periods as a monitoring system for the current load on one of our servers, but currently I can only keep it up for a few hours before it gets killed.

I tried using the heap snapshot in the profile tab, and if I compare the snapshot before and after a few calls to drawCharts it seems like the leaked objects are SVG elements from the chart itself, but it's possible I'm interpreting those results incorrectly.

I've reproduced the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/dv5nK/4/

After about 20 mins, the about:memory page in chrome will start to show high memory consumption around 150 MB for me. This effect can be seen faster by shortening the setTimeout to 100 ms.

EDIT: fixed memory usage stat

Comment: The memory leak is a known issue, and it's probably nothing in your code that's causing it.  I think it relates to the browser's garbage collection on removed SVG elements, but I'm not certain.  The Visualization API dev team is investigating the problem.

Comment: @asgallant You are right. I've added the issues as an answer and will accept them as soon as it lets me. I ended up going with smoothie charts since it is designed for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you are building a new chart for each update (with new
>   `google.visualization.SomeChart()`) then when you are done with the
>   previous instance, you must call `clearChart()` on it,  otherwise memory
>   will accumulate.  Google Charts can't tell that the chart has been
>   garbage collected, and it needs an explicit clearChart() call to
>   unlink event handlers from the DOM.

source: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1021

Comment: This answer is correct and it should be marked as the correct solution. It worked for me. I can clearly see the "Nodes" line going down while i'm monitoring my page.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug. [issue1](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=209) [issue2](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1021)

Comment: Issue posted at 2010 and at 2015 yet not fixed? wow, thats interesting from google. I also have page where mainly google graphs are and after night its crashed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with memory usage from Google charts. Was able to fix my issue by modifying the clearChart() function in Google code.

Here is the full answer:

[Google Chart Constant Redrawing Memory Increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805964/google-chart-constant-redrawing-memory-increase/18839757#18839757)

Answer (score 0):

What I notice is that, event listeners are not being removed so elements are not being released from memory.

I suspect this line:

```
if (this.vals.getNumberOfRows() > this.max) {
    this.vals.removeRow(0);
}
```

Is there any way to make sure that you are removing all event listeners attached to the row you are removing?

Comment: I'm looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) and I don't see any method for that.

Comment: If you cannot find it, then I am afraid you are out of luck unless it is open source and you can make a fix for it. You should report the issue if not done already.

Comment: Yes, I actually just checked and there are several issues already open regarding this. It seems to be a bug. Thanks for your help. I'll add a link to the relevant issue.

Comment: Oh I've got an idea. Have you tried to remove the whole chart and reinitialize it with new set of data?

Comment: Try destorying the entire chart, and recreate. If that does not release memory, then I really don't know what to do.

Comment: @Juno, destroying the chart and rebuilding it does not release the memory.