# Google Chart Constant Redrawing Memory Increase

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm redrawing the chart based on new data each second, and it works and looks great, but I notice it increase memory like 1 MB usage each second. Any way to fix this? I notice if I just have static charts, then the memory stabilizes, but once I add constant redrawing (in order to update data), the memory usage never stops.

At first I thought it was because I was creating a new instance of the chart each time, so I change the code so it was only redrawing the same instance each time, but that didn't help much at all.

Anyone know how to fix it?  Do I need to dump the old chart first somehow?

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(test);

var chart;
var chartOptions;
var chartCreate;

function test() {
    chart = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chart.addColumn('string', 'Lorem');
    chart.addColumn('number', 'Ipsum');
    chart.addRows([
            ['', 0]
    ]);
    chartOptions = {};
    chartCreate = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
          chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);
    ]);
}

function test2() {
    chart.removeRows(0, 5);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataSpaceArray.length; ++i) {
        chart.addRow([dataTimeArray[i], dataSpaceArray[i], dataSpeedArray[i]]);
    }
        chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);
}

setTimeout(test2,1000)
```

Comment: The memory leak on redraw is a known issue.  There's nothing you can do about it as far as I am aware.  The Visualization API dev team knows about it and is looking into it.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that? That seems really weird, it pretty much means you can't update the data in the charts then.

Comment: FYI, the newest release candidate version (load v1.1 instead of v1) includes some fixes for memory leak issues.

Comment: I have tried for two days now different ways get past this but nothing works. Among many things, I've tried trashing the entire containing div (with the best result though of abt. 400 kB leak/update). @Alex solution didn't do a thing. How does one load the v1.1, @asgallant?

Comment: When you call `google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: [/* packages list */], callback: drawChart});`, replace the `1` with `1.1`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! With 1.1 the leak (if any) is negligible. Overall consumption higher though (~15MB from ~7MB). Works on pc but very sluggish on the Raspberry Pi (another story :-). You should consider 1.1 a good Answer to this Question!

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this by globaly store the chart. Before draw the chart, you need to check if chart has been instantiated. If not, create the new chart object else call clearChart() method before draw it. Like this:

```
//Store all chart objects in a global array to avoid memory leak
var charts = [];

function drawChart(chartName, element, data, chartOptions) {
   if (charts[chartName] === undefined || charts[chartName] === null) {
          charts[chartName] = new google.visualization.LineChart(group);
   } else {
          charts[chartName].clearChart();
   }
   charts[chartName].draw(dataTable, chartOptions);
}
```

Comment: confirming that this works, but after clearChart I had to instantiate again - new google.visualization.LineChart(group);

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue, was able to fix it by adding a few lines to Google's clearChart() function.

```
W.clearChart = function() {

    //this fixes the leak
    hv = {};
    iv = {};
    jv = {};

    ...
};
```

More Details:

1. Here's the Google file I made the change to:

https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/4086f2e8fc632adc52e6d6795a5637a4/format+en,default,corechart.I.js

1. Download this file, make the change mentioned above. In your code, add a script tag to load above file from your webserver and comment out the following line:

   // google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
2. The memory will go up but will come back down on it's own after a few minutes.
3. I'm using clearChart() but if you don't want to clear the chart, then create your own function (e.g. memoryLeakFix()) and call it periodically.
4. Here's a test page (the 1.js is the modified file from step 1). It basically creates new chart and redraws every 100ms. You will see memory go up but hit "Stop" link to stop the redrawing and wait a few minutes and memory will come down.

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head>
>     <title></title>
>   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
>   <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"                                          type="text/javascript"></script>
>
>   <script src="1.js"                                          type="text/javascript"></script>
>
>
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>
>       //init google charts
> //        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
>       google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
>
>   </script>
>
>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <a href='#' onclick='stop()'>Stop</a>
>   <div class='chart'></div>
>
>   <script>
>
>       var chart; var table;
>
>       function createChart(container)
>       {
>           if(chart != undefined)
>               chart.clearChart();
>
>           //init chart
>           chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container[0]);
>
>           //init chart data
>           if(table == undefined)
>           {
>               table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
>
>               table.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
>               table.addColumn('number', 'Value');
>
>               var count = 0;
>
>               //periodically add rows
>               setInterval(function()
>               {
>                   //add row
>                   table.addRows([ [new Date(), count++]]);    
>               }, 1000);
>
>
>           }
>       }
>
>
>       //start redrawing
>       var id = setInterval(function()
>       {
>           createChart($('.chart'));
>
>           drawChart();
>       }, 100);
>
>       //stop redrawing
>       function stop()
>       {
>           clearInterval(id);
>       }
>
>       //draw chart
>       function drawChart()
>       {
>           chart.draw(table, { curveType: "function",
>
>               width:      250, 
>               height:     250,
>               pointSize:  1,
>               legend:     { position: 'none' },
>               chartArea: { 'width': '90%', left: 50 },
>           });
>       }
>
>   </script>   
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: I can see that your impressive hack can avoid some memory leaks.  But people should be aware that this will be brittle in a couple ways.  When used with other ways of reusing charts, particularly in dashboards, there are likely to be complications.  Also, when a new version of the library is created, the compiled names of classes and internal variables will likely be different.  But hopefully, the new version will have fixed these memory leaks.