# Google chart keeps drawing

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So I have this chart:

```
        google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawAxisTickColors,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});


 function drawAxisTickColors() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
   data.addColumn('number', 'value');

   var dateArr2 = (<?php echo json_encode($dateArr); ?>);
   console.log(dateArr2);

   var bitcoinArr = (<?php echo json_encode($numbers); ?>);
   console.log(bitcoinArr);

   bitcoinArr = bitcoinArr.map(Number);

  var array = [];

  var length = Math.min(dateArr2.length, bitcoinArr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
     array.push([ new Date(dateArr2[i]), bitcoinArr[i] ]);
  }

   data.addRows(array);

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
  containerId: 'control_div',
  options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
          chartOptions: {
              height: 50,
              width: 600,
              chartArea: {
                  width: '80%'
              }
          }
      }
  }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'LineChart',
  containerId: 'chart_div',
  options: {
    width: 620,
    chartArea: {
      width: '80%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'hh:ss',
      slantedText: false,
      maxAlternation: 1
    }
  }
  });

  function setOptions() {
  var firstDate;
  var lastDate;
  var v = control.getState();

  if (v.range) {
    document.getElementById('dbgchart').innerHTML = v.range.start + ' to ' + v.range.end;
    firstDate = new Date(v.range.start.getTime() + 1);
    lastDate = new Date(v.range.end.getTime() - 1);
    data.setValue(v.range.start.getMonth(), 0, firstDate);
    data.setValue(v.range.end.getMonth(), 0, lastDate);
  } else {
    firstDate = data.getValue(0, 0);
    lastDate = data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0);
  }

  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = firstDate.getMonth(); i <= lastDate.getMonth(); i++) {
    ticks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
  }

  chart.setOption('hAxis.ticks', ticks);
  chart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min', firstDate);
  chart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', lastDate);
  if (dash) {
    chart.draw();
  }
  }

  setOptions();

  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', setOptions);

   var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
   dash.bind([control], [chart]);
  dash.draw(data);
}
```

I use this chart to show import per user, but every time I draw the chart this happens:

[image]

As you can see the chart keeps it's old data, this slows down my website. I tried clearChart() but my chart ingores it's or give's an error:

```
clearchart is not a function
```

I also tried this:

[Google Chart Constant Redrawing Memory Increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805964/google-chart-constant-redrawing-memory-increase)

but this doesn't seem to work for me.

What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

Comment: `clearChart` is a `chart` method, you're using a `chartWrapper`, you must first get the chart --> `chart.getChart().clearChart()` -- but if it is a data issue, this most likely won't help. but i only see one `addRows` statement, is there more code somewhere that adds additional data?

Comment: @WhiteHat Well I made a dashboard where you can see how much a user has imported over a peroid of time, if you have 10 users, you load the chart and data 10 times, but I have about 200 users and my site can't handel that much data loaded in.

Comment: what about only showing a single user at a time, with a drop down or something to select the user?

Comment: @WhiteHat I am doing smomthing like that I show a list of users and if you click on a user a form appears you fill in a begin date and end date and the chart draws if you press submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it

don't call the google api a 100 times